# Particular case of Green's theorem

Tags: scattering, integration

Suppose we have $u(r)=\sum_{\lambda=1}^{\infty} a_{\lambda} u_{\lambda}(r), \, 0 \leq r \leq a$ in this article [Introduction to R-matrix theory in atomic
physics](https://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/mariko.dunseath-terao/IP2004/psrmat1.pdf)

they say that
$$\int_{0}^{a}\left[u_{\lambda} \frac{d^{2} u}{d r^{2}}-u \frac{d^{2} u_{\lambda}}{d r^{2}}\right] dr=\left[u_{\lambda}\frac{du}{d r}-u \frac{du_{\lambda}}{d r}\right]_{r=a}$$

using Green’s theorem.
What is this  Green’s theorem they are talking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\int _0^a dr \left [ u_\lambda\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}-u\frac{d^2u_\lambda}{dr^2} \right ]=\int _0^a dr \frac{d}{dr} \left [ u_\lambda\frac{du}{dr}-u\frac{du_\lambda}{dr} \right ] = \left [ u_\lambda\frac{du}{dr}-u\frac{du_\lambda}{dr} \right ] \Bigg |_{r=a},
\end{equation}
assuming regularity at $r=0$